# Access class instance from a function passed into a React component and triggered there

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, reactjs

I have a Backbone/React app. I'm trying to keep all my backbone logic in the backbone View (FoodList in this example), so that I can pass methods into the components, have the components trigger them, and then run the necessary logic within the view (i.e. manipulate backbone collection), keeping backbone's business out of react's business.

The trouble I'm running into is when I try to access the `this` value from my `doSomething` method passed into the component, I'm getting the window, not the FoodView instance. How can I bind the FoodList instance given this situation?

```
## BACKBONE VIEW:

FoodList = require '../components/FoodList'

class FoodView extends Backbone.View

    initialize:  =>        
        ...done() =>
        @renderFood()


    renderFood: ->            
        React.render(
                <FoodList
                    foods={@collection.foods.toJSON()}
                    doSomething={doSomething} ## method of interest
                />, 
                app.pageEl
            )

    doSomething: (e) ->
        console.log @ ## returns window.
        id = $(e.currentTarget).data('id') 
        @collection.makeAChange(id) ## I want to access the FoodView instance's collection


## REACT COMPONENT:

FoodList = React.createClass

    handleSomething: (e) ->
      @props.doSomething(e)

    render: ->
      return(
        ...
        <li data-id={id} onClick={@handleSomething}>dynamically generated</li>
        ...
      )
```

Comment: What version of React? What does this compile to in JavaScript?

Comment: Does it work to do `doSomething={@doSomething}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CoffeeScript, you just need to use a fat arrow function to automatically bind the `FoodView::doSomething` method to the instance. See also [Bound functions](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow).

```
class FoodView extends Backbone.View
    doSomething: (e) =>
        // `@` refers to the  FoodView instance
```

which is equivalent to

```
class FoodView extends Backbone.View
    constructor: ->
        @doSomething = @doSomething.bind(@)

    doSomething: (e) ->
        // `@` refers to the  FoodView instance
```